# Press Enter Button To Login

Tags: c#

Please I am working on a login form, I want it to be that once a user has entered the password and pressed the enter button keyboard, without leaving the textBox, it will just login straight away. How will I do it please?

Comment: You should've mentioned whether it is a web or win form.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the `AcceptButton` property of your form to the login button.

Check [MSDN Form.AcceptButton Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Gets or sets the button on the form that is clicked when the user
>   presses the ENTER key.

Comment: @OyeleyeOsuolale:- You are welcome. You can accept the answer (A right tick mark turns green when clicked)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a Panel like this

```
<asp:Panel DefaultButton="YOUR_BUTTON_ID" runat="server" ID="Panel1">

</asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void textBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        button.PerformClick();
    }
}
```